# crypt module not found (python3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, crypt

I'm using python 3.7,the **crypt** module that used to be built-in python 2.x, now i can't seem to find it.
I tried https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html but it's source code uses  `_crypt` which also i can't download any help is appreciated.

```
import crypt
```

i get this error

```
    import _crypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_crypt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Windows then it's because [`crypt`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/crypt.html) is a [*Unix Specific Service*](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unix.html).

Comment: i have linux kali installed as subsystem what should i do ?

Comment: Are you running this on kali linux?

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled `crypto` and installed it again and it fixed my problem.

```
pip uninstall crypto
```

```
pip install crypto
```